# Why would you use Amazon API Gateway to access S3 rather than the traditional S3 API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking into the Amazon API Gateway. Is there a reason to use it as an S3 Proxy rather than making calls to the S3 API directly?

Comment: I commented previously based on what was, somehow, a total misreading of your question.  Let me try again.  You're asking "I see that this is possible but I don't see the point, so... what am I missing?"

Comment: I can't think of a use case involving api gateway to access S3 instead of using its own endpoints. API Gateway is useful with services like Lambda

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. You have answered my question perfectly. Somebody recommended API Gateway and I was trying to work out why. I think the only advantage would be if I wanted to use AWS to store my users - the API Gateway would handle authorisation.